# How to use NetSuite SuiteTalk to retrieve a list of Amortization Templates

Tags: netsuite

How can I get a list of Amortization Templates from the NetSuite SuiteTalk web service using C#?

**Background:**
I have been asked to present a list of Amortization Templates so that a user may pick a template to associate with an item purchased or expense.

The list I am attempting to return can be found in NetSuite's UI by navigating to: Lists | Accounting | Amortization Templates.

I am struggling how to determine the correct SuiteTalk Search type and Class. I have been looking through the classes generated from the WSDL and the only thing that seems close is the RevRecTemplate (which doesn't seem correct).

My questions are: Can you retrieved Amortization Templates (name and internalId) using NetSuite SuiteTalk?  If so, what is the Class and SearchType to use?

**Things I have tried:**  I created a "test" amortization schedule using NetSuite's UI.  Then attempted to use the following code to retrieve the template.

```
    // Define the search criteria        
    RevRecTemplateSearchBasic searchAmortizationSchedules = new RevRecTemplateSearchBasic();                
    searchAmortizationSchedules.name = new SearchStringField();
    searchAmortizationSchedules.name.@operator = SearchStringFieldOperator.notEmpty;
    searchAmortizationSchedules.name.operatorSpecified = true;

    // Perform Search
    SearchResult searchResults = NS.search(searchAmortizationSchedules);
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to NetSuite Support, it is not possible to return a list of Amortization Templates from the SuiteTalk web service.  We are using the NetSuite 2015_1 version of the web service.

NetSuite Support added this feature as an enhancement request. It may be available in later versions.